# Can't add custom attribute to window object using javascript

Tags: javascript, window, custom-attributes

How can i add custom attribute to `window` object using javascript. I am doing it like:

```
var mypopupWindow = window.open(url);
mypopupWindow.myProperty = window;
```

But myProperty remains `undefined` when i try to access it from mypopupWindow, i am using IE.9.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this works for me in Chrome

```
var originWindow = this;
var popupWindow = window.open()
popupWindow.a = "b"
originWindow.a = "c"
  popupWindow.setTimeout(function () {
    alert(this.a) //b

  },500);
```

If i run this code on JSBin, the alert displays "b".

So the `window.open`'s returned `window`'s propertie is assigned fine.

*You can of course open the console in the new Window in chrome and the `Window` has a propertie `a` with the value `"b"`*

Heres a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/omafod/1/edit)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can set these attributes reliably on the window object itself, but you could set them on the windows document object instead.

Comment: As I said, we can't set them **reliably**, but thanks for the downvote. The reason is that IE9 is opening the window asynchronously, so it is trying to set the value of the myProperty attribute before the window has opened.